# I get the problem Mapping Error: mapping types: entityqueryable to ienumerable

Tags: c#, api, specifications

When I use Specification Pattern and try to compare Enum Properties from class with string from parameters I get this exception: Translation of method 'object.ToString' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

This is my code:

`

```
[Table("Doctors")]
    public class Doctors : Entity
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required!")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The legnt of this field must be less than 100 characters!")]
    public string Doctors_name { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required!")]
    public Specialty Specialty { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required!")]
    public string Password_hash { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required!")]
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<Visitations> Visitations { get; set; } = null!;
}`
```

`

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum Specialty
{
    Base_Surgery = 0,

    Anesthesiology = 1,

    Dermatology = 2,
    
    Neurosurgery = 3,
    
    Urology = 4,
    
    Thoracic_Surgery = 5,
}`
```

`

```
public abstract class Specifications<TEntity> : ISpecifications<TEntity>
        where TEntity : Entity
{
    protected Specifications() { }

    protected Specifications(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? criteria) =>
        Criteria = criteria;

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? Criteria { get; }

    public List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> Include_Expression { get; } = new();
    
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>? Order_by_Expression { get; private set; }

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>? Order_by_Descending_Expression { get; private set; }

    protected void Insert_Include(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> include_Expression) =>
        Include_Expression.Add(include_Expression);

    protected void Insert_Order_By(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> order_by_Expression) =>
        Order_by_Expression = order_by_Expression;

    protected void Insert_Order_By_Descending(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> order_by_Decsending_Expression) =>
        Order_by_Descending_Expression = order_by_Decsending_Expression;
}`
```

`

```
public class Specifications_Evaluator<TEntity>
        where TEntity : Entity
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Get_all_Information(IQueryable<TEntity> query_Information, ISpecifications<TEntity> specifications)
    {
        var result = query_Information;

        if (specifications.Criteria != null)
        {
            result = result.Where(specifications.Criteria);
        }

        if (specifications.Order_by_Expression != null)
        {
            result = result.OrderBy(specifications.Order_by_Expression);
        }

        if (specifications.Order_by_Descending_Expression != null)
        {
            result = result.OrderByDescending(specifications.Order_by_Descending_Expression);
        }

        // Includes all expression-based includes
        result = specifications.Include_Expression.Aggregate(result, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        return result;
    }
}`
```

`

```
public class DoctorsSpecializations : Specifications<Doctors>
    {
        public DoctorsSpecializations(string specializations) : base(x => x.Specialty.ToString() == specializations)
        {
        }
    }`
```

`

```
public IEnumerable<Get_Doctors_Result_DTO> Find_Doctors_Speciality(string speciality)
{
    var result = _unit_Of_Work.Doctros_Repository.Find_with_Specifications_Pattern(new DoctorsSpecializations(speciality));

    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Doctors>, IEnumerable<Get_Doctors_Result_DTO>>(result);
}`
```

I want to get all list of doctors by concrete speciality